# How To Add Active Class To a Current Navbar Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hope you all doing great.
I've been trying to add the (active class )to each of the navbar links when the user is on that specific section of the page with this
[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX1T5mR_yVc&list=PLfVxbRIcicRHYojr5u_ztTWJwhG78Kaay&ab_channel=EGATOR) (i'm stuck at 2:45:05) and no success so far can anyone tell me what i did wrong .thank you.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(' nav .container ul');

const navItems = menu.querySelectorAll('li');
navItems.forEach(item => {
  const link = item.querySelector('a');
  ink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    link.classList.add(".active");
  });
});
```

```css
nav .container ul li a.active {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: var(--color-white);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <h3> AMANI DEV </h3>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have a typo as you can see if you run the snippet.

Comment: There is a typo `ink` should be `link`.

Comment: thank you, i correct it but still not working

Comment: Do you want to remove the active tag from the current active link and then add it to the new clicked link?

Comment: @Andy yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typo with `ink` not `link`.
2. When you assign a class with `classList` you don't include the `.`: `classList.add('active')`.
3. In your CSS `background` should probably be `background-color`.
4. If you want to remove the other active links before applying the new one you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the links and use `classList.remove('active')` on each one.

You may find [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) easier to manage. Rather than attaching multiple listeners to multiple elements attach *one* listener to the list element that watches out for events from its child elements as they "bubble up the DOM. You can then check that [the clicked element is a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), remove the active classes from the previous link(s), and then apply the active class [to the clicked link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Here's an example using event delegation.

```js
// Cache the list, and the items
const list = document.querySelector(' nav .container ul');
const links = list.querySelectorAll('a');

// Add one listener to the list element
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// If the clicked element is a link remove all
// the active classes from the other links, and then
// add the active class to the link that was clicked on
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('a')) {
    links.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
:root { --color-white: white; --color-primary: red; }

.active {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  color: var(--color-white);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <h3> AMANI DEV </h3>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you so much. #2 was the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `querySelectorAll` in **a** tag not on the **li** tag. Just do this and do let me know.

Comment: sill not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
  }
})
```

**here a demo code:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#myNav li').forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('#myNav li').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <h3> AMANI DEV </h3>
    </a>
    <ul id="myNav">
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: didn't work! can you specify where should i write it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uweq6f2r/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code in the following line :

```
 ink.addEventListener('click',() => {
```

to

```
 link.addEventListener('click',() => {
```

to be like this

```
const menu = document.querySelector(' nav .container ul');

const navItems = menu.querySelectorAll('li');
navItems.forEach(item => {
  const link = item.querySelector('a');
  link.addEventListener('click',() => {
    link.classList.add(".active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you quite sure about this line: `link.classList.add(".active");`?

Comment: yes, i've correct that already yet not working

Comment: @Andy i'm following that tut.

Comment: :) I was trying to point out to Omar that the line won't work.

Comment: @Andy you should've pointed out to me as well because that line was the problem :9

Comment: @Andy Thanks for noticing, I'll try to focus more next time :)

Comment: @OmarHussien you'll find using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar useful for testing your code before you post an answer.

Comment: @Andy I will be sure to use it next time, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
// selecting all a element on the page
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// adding a click event on all elements 
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // if we click first thing is deleting the active class from all link
    links.forEach((link) => {
      link.classList.remove('active')
    })
    // then in the end add the active class only in the correct one
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

Comment: You should a) add a description to explain your code b) move `e.target.classList.add('active')` _outside_ of the loop.